Standard or Custom Policy with client asking for invalid scope
I've looked.
https://oauth.net/2/scope/
(and looked much more than that)
But I can only find ambiguous information.
Scenario 1.
If client asks for scopes
"read write view"
read write and view ARE legitimate scopes in my system.
but the specific client only has read and write
So I return the ones that match and are legit
return "read write"
OR
throw an exception "You asked for view, you don't have view"
.....
Scenario 2
If client asks for scopes
"read write peanutbutter"
read write and view ARE legitimate scopes in my system.
but peanutbutter is not a valid scope in my sysetm.
So I return the ones that match and are legit
return "read write"
OR
throw an exception "You asked for peanutbutter, sorry"
..
OR with the above permutations, it is my (the STS) choice on what to do?
thanks!
